# how to evenly distribute values in array python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Suppose I have df with 16 index and I want to evenly distribute number A-L

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
```

My desired output is:

```
1       A
2       A
3       B
4       B
5       C
6       C
7       D
8       D
9       E
10      F
11      G
12      H
13      I
14      J
15      K
16      L
```

Is there any possible way to do this

rname is second column
, df2 is first column ,
my way was np.repeat(rname, np.ceil(len(df2) / len(rname)))[:len(df2)]

Comment: Kindly show your attempt for this

Comment: np.repeat(rname, np.ceil(len(df2) / len(rname)))[:len(df2)] @FAHADSIDDIQUI

Comment: You say you want "evenly distributed values but your desired output is biased on the lower end. In other words, you've got more AA, BB, than the single count I, J, K, etc. values. Do you want the bias?

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
df['new_col'] = np.sort((np.arange(16) % 12) +1)
```

Comment: This will not produce the desired output.

Comment: What if second column is string

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.read_clipboard(header=None)
ar_int = [int(x) for x in np.arange(1, 13, (12/16))]
df[1] = ar_int


print(df)


    0   1
0   1   1
1   2   1
2   3   2
3   4   3
4   5   4
5   6   4
6   7   5
7   8   6
8   9   7
9   10  7
10  11  8
11  12  9
12  13  10
13  14  10
14  15  11
15  16  12
```

For your string comment, you can do this.

```
alphabet='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
ar_int = [alphabet[int(x)] for x in np.arange(0, 12, (12/16))]
df[1] = ar_int
print(df)

    0   1
0   1   A
1   2   A
2   3   B
3   4   C
4   5   D
5   6   D
6   7   E
7   8   F
8   9   G
9   10  G
10  11  H
11  12  I
12  13  J
13  14  J
14  15  K
15  16  L
```

Comment: Hi, What if second column is a string

Answer (score 1):

This may help you

```
import numpy as np
rname = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L']

n_times = int(np.ceil(len(data) / len(rname)))

lst = np.repeat(rname,n_times)

n_elems = (len(df) - len(rname))

output = list(lst[:n_elems*n_times]) + list(rname[n_elems:])
print(output)
```

**OUtput**

```
['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L']
```